# GLSL: rotation with a rotation vector?

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I am trying to do skeletal animation with GLSL. For each bone, I have a translation(x,y,z) and a rotation(pitch, roll, yaw) (in degrees). I could construct a 4x4 matrix for each bone but that would take alot of register space in the shader, so I would like to only have to store the 6 values I have per bone, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: What don't you know how to do? You can pass the values in as either 6 floats, or as 2 vec3s. Do you mean you don't know how to calculate the composed matrix of all the operations using those values? Also, are you sure that a single 4x4 matrix in a register is really a space problem? I imagine calculating the 4x4 matrix for each vertex or pixel is going to be processor intensive. Is that the trade-off you want to make?

Comment: Its not a single 4x4 matrix, its a 4x4 matrix per bone. What I don't know how to do is how to rotate a point using the rotation vec3 I have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I don't know how to do is how to rotate a point using the rotation vec3 I have.

Simple: don't.

Yaw-pitch-roll is a terrible way to encode an orientation, *especially* for an animation system. Use a quaternion instead. It's 4 values rather than 3, and the code for rotation is well-known.

Also, it doesn't require heavy-weight operations like `sin` and `cos`.

If you want to compare and contrast the effort needed, consider the math.

Given a quaternion `q`, a position `v`, you need to do this to rotate it:

```
vec3 temp = cross(q.xyz, v) + q.w * v;
vec3 rotated = v + 2.0*cross(q.xyz, temp);
```

That's a fair bit of math. Now, consider what you have to do for your YPR case, given :

```
vec3 cosYPR = cos(ypr);
vec3 sinYPR = sin(ypr);
```

That's not everything. But that's *enough*. That's three `cos` and three `sin` operations. These are *not fast* operations. That alone probably takes about as long as the entire quaternion/vector rotation computation. But after doing this, you now have to do several multiplies and adds to compute the 3x3 matrix. And then, after all that, you *still* have to do the actual matrix multiply to rotate the vector.

Comment: what would be more efficient? using quaternions or constructing a rotation matrix in the shader?

Comment: Shouldn't `vec3 rotated = v + 2.0*cross(q.xyz, temp);` be even more efficient (avoids 1 DOT and 1 MAD)? Though not sure if that requires unit quat and yours doesn't (but then again, who uses non-unit quats for rotations?).

Comment: You say that `sin` and `cos` are heavy-weight. However, I've seen some people on the web say they are just one clock cycle on many GPUs. Can you point to any proofs about them being slow?

Comment: @v.shashenko: I've seen people on the web say lots of things. Do you have any actual links? Also, do note that, even if each of those *vector-wise* sin/cos operations were one cycle, that doesn't take into account the cost of using them to build a matrix and then doing a matrix multiply.

Comment: @NicolBolas: One of such links https://stackoverflow.com/a/11823383/1894053

Comment: @v.shashenko: Yes, one guy with 18 posts on Gamedev said they're single-cycle, so it totally must be true... The actual conversation on that link is kind of missing the point. For example, on AMD's pre-GCN hardware, they did indeed support single-cycle sin/cos operations. But it's one cycle *per-component*. Note that you actually need 3 sins and 3 coses. That's a lot more than 1 cycle. And again, as I pointed out, that doesn't take into account building the matrix from those values and doing the matrix multiply. Direct quaternion transform *always wins*.